# Get key press for only when got pressed and get it again when it is released and pressed again

Tags: c++, windows, io, keyboard

I'm trying to get key input for only when it is pressed like not for if we keep it pressed.

I want it to stop the input until it is "released" and "pressed" again, but I am unable to do it.

my code:

```
while(isRunning)
{
    if(GetKeyState('K') & 0x8000) 
    {
        std::cout << "K is Pressed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output when pressed:

> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed
> K is Pressed

but what I want my out to be is a

> K is Pressed

and I want it to print it again when I "Release" it and "Press" it again.

Comment: You should intercept and handle windows messages like `WM_KEYDOWN`

Comment: @MatG I looked at this documentaion here: one of the links I referred to is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown but how do you get the UINT message and WPARAM wparam. I cant seem to find them

Answer (score 1):

If you only want notification of state changes, you should not be calling `GetKeyState` in a loop. Instead, you should respond to [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and [`WM_KEYUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup) messages.

However, in a Windows console application, you cannot process window messages for the console window, because your application does not own that window. Therefore, you will have to use [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) and process [`KEY_EVENT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str) events instead. See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65457519-bccd-49d2-bcb1-03d74a1898a4/c-and-windows-api-in-console-application-can-do-a-messsage-loop?forum=vclanguage) for further information on why it is not possible to create a standard window message loop for console applications.

Comment: I looked around a little bit but how do I get UINT message, its always a parameter in all the documentations but it never shows how to get the "UINT message" nor the "WPARAM wParam" one of the links I referred to is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown and also this isn't a gui app

Comment: @RAGBOT: Since you have now added the information that you need this for a console application, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library are you using but the thought behind getting a key press is creating an array of type `bool` such as `bool lastKeys[256];` and keeping record of all the keys pressed in the last frame, you'll need to update it every time a key is pressed or each frame... then when you want a key press you'll need to ask `if (GetKeyState('k') && !lastKeys['k'])` If your library has this feature this is probably how it's done behind the scenes.
try to make it as efficient as possible.